# RestSharp showing Error of Cannot create an instance of an interface have to manually deserialize

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, restsharp

I have RestSharp (which is like HttpClient)  call and return data from a Web Api method

I'm getting this error  `{"Cannot create an instance of an interface."}`

My code looks like this:

```
public List<Interest> GetInterests()
{
    var request = new RestRequest(apiPath + "GetInterests", Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
    var response = Client.Execute<List<Interest>>(request);
    return response.Data;
}
```

My **response.Content** shows below.

Now the problem seems to be that the DATA is there as JSON in the Content property of the response object. I can manually deserialize it from there. But is was automatically deserializing it into the Data property before,  I'm not sure what is happening now.

**If I manually deserialize the json, it works - but why do I need to do this?**

```
List<Interest> results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Interest>>(response.Content);
```

Response:

`"StatusCode: OK, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 5597)"`

**JSON code returned**

```
[
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":1,
      "InterestName":"Nursing",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":2,
      "InterestName":"Creating/Supporting Networks of Community Partners",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":3,
      "InterestName":"Epidemiology",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":4,
      "InterestName":"Maternal",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":5,
      "InterestName":"Healthcare for the Homeless",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":6,
      "InterestName":"HIV/AIDS, STD",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":7,
      "InterestName":"Nutrition",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":8,
      "InterestName":"Physical Activity",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":9,
      "InterestName":"Oral Health",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":10,
      "InterestName":"Public Health Communication",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":11,
      "InterestName":"Emergency Preparedness and Response",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":12,
      "InterestName":"Public Health Policy",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":13,
      "InterestName":"Tuberculosis",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":14,
      "InterestName":"Teen Pregnancy Prevention",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":15,
      "InterestName":"Vital Registration",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":16,
      "InterestName":"Chronic Disease",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":17,
      "InterestName":"Finance & Management",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":18,
      "InterestName":"Quality Improvement",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":19,
      "InterestName":"Healthy Community Design",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":20,
      "InterestName":"Behavioral Health and Healthcare Integration",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":21,
      "InterestName":"Rx Drug Misuse and Abuse",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":22,
      "InterestName":"Injury Prevention",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":23,
      "InterestName":"School Health",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":24,
      "InterestName":"Worksite Wellness",
      "AddDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.61",
      "ModDate":"2016-07-01T17:03:21.64",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   },
   {
      "InternInterests":[

      ],
      "OfficeInterests":[

      ],
      "InterestId":25,
      "InterestName":"Access to Healthy Foods",
      "AddDate":"2016-08-03T08:10:45.4",
      "ModDate":"2016-08-03T08:10:45.4",
      "AddUser":"System",
      "ModUser":"System",
      "IsDeleted":false
   }
]
```

**If I manually deserialize the json, it works - but why do I need to do this?**

```
List<Interest> results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Interest>>(response.Content);
```

Comment: @Ed   thx   yes the json was nasty

Answer (score 16):

I ran into the same problem. In my case I created a custom object (in your case is Interest object), which had a ICollection list of objects. So, I remove that ICollection and make it as a List of objects. Check whether the Interest has any Interface related property and try make as concrete object property.

Check InternInterests and OfficeInterests property it might be using any kind of interface collection.

Comment: It happens if you have a type constraint on execute method. Like Where T:new()

Comment: Same with IEnumerable, or in my case seq in F# - seems like the JSON.net serializer is more forgiving and works with these types compared with the RestSharp serializer

Comment: We just ran into the same problem, and this was exactly the solution.  Apparently the RestSharp implementation of the JsonSerializer is somewhat naive and can't handle interface list properties (`IList`, `IEnumerable`, etc).  Slightly annoying -- so far as I'm aware JSON.net handles this just fine -- but whatever.  At least we know what to do when this happens.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I fix the issue with the following code:

`var client = new RestClient();
client.AddHandler("application/json", NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Default);
client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri(Host);`

Where the class NewtonsoftJsonSerializer is a custom deserializer:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp.Deserializers;

namespace IntegrationTests.Common
{
    class NewtonsoftJsonSerializer : IDeserializer
    {
        private Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer;

        public NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            this.serializer = serializer;
        }

        public string DateFormat { get; set; }

        public string Namespace { get; set; }

        public string RootElement { get; set; }

        public T Deserialize<T>(RestSharp.IRestResponse response)
        {
            var content = response.Content;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
        }

        public static NewtonsoftJsonSerializer Default
        {
            get
            {
                return new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer()
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

@JUVER Your handler does help - Thank you.
2 comments:

- You may want some error handling in Deserialize, otherwise errors end
  being masked as Deserialize errors and
- private Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer; is never used. It can be
  removed along with the constructor.

Here is Deserialize with some error handling:

```
public T Deserialize<T>(RestSharp.IRestResponse response)
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) throw new System.UnauthorizedAccessException();

    if (!response.IsSuccessful) throw (new System.Exception(response.Content));

    var content = response.Content;

    // Note 8/31/2023 I no longer recommend or use Json.NET due to its novel (IMO incorrect) parsing of string which look like date-times, to datetime types.
    // See https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862 for concurring opinions
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
}
```

Comment: Just wondering what is need for checking both Ok and IsSuccessful.
If not OK then IsSuccessful will be false right or can it be true??

Comment: Good question. I don't have a good answer. I don't what I was thinking or even who I was working for. I may have had a good reason, but the more I look at it now. I see several problems which I will edit in the my example. response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK is wrong since there codes other OK (200) which may indicate success. The implementation of IsSuccessful is not the clear either. It checks ResponseStatus, which has a comment:    /// Status of the request. Will return Error for transport errors.
    /// HTTP errors will still return ResponseStatus.Completed, check StatusCode instead